# SDK Manager won't start Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: android, windows-7, sdk, 64-bit

I know this problem has been addressed before several times, but rather than comment on an old question I decided to make a new one with (hopefully) updated information.

As the title says, no matter what I do I cannot get the SDK Manager to run.  I have tried installing both the 32- and 64-bit versions of jdk1.7.0 but no luck.

Currently I have both the jdk (32-bit) and the sdk installed in the C:\ directory.  As many have said I changed the environment variable below to reflect the locations.  Namely:

Variable name: PATH
Variable value:

> **C:\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\;** C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\

(Obviously I only added the first two values)

Somebody out there must have had the same difficulty setting this up who can help me out here.  I had no problem installing everything on my 32-bit Win7 machine, but the 64-bit is my main computer and I really need to have the SDK with me if I am going to learn how to use it.

**(EDIT: Solved!)**

The problem I was having was that a command prompt window would pop up then the SDK Manager would start to load then instantly crash.

Strangely, someone else with a very similar computer to mine just installed with no problems whatsoever.  Weird.

I finally added another environment variable:

Variable name: JAVA_HOME

Variable value: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\

and it worked!

Thanks for all the help everyone.  I hope this can help someone else who might have the same problem.

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to run the SDK manager? As far as I remember (sitting on Linux now), Google advises against putting the Android SDK folder directly on your C:-drive - I guess it's because of the permission problems writing to the C:-drive.
What happens if you put the Android SDK folder inside your userfolder instead?

Comment: I am running just fine on Win7 64-bit and never ran into any issues.  One difference is that I am using jdk1.6.0_26 instead of 1.7.0.  I've also installed the JDK to the default in Program Files.  My android sdk is in C:\Development\Android, which is about the same as yours.  What errors are you getting?  When you say it doesn't run, what does it do exactly?

Comment: It is working fine for me and I put the SDK in C: root. 
Do you have Eclipse 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: If you're adding the JDK to your path, it needs to be the path to the JDK binaries, not the root of the JDK. So for your example above, that would be "C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin"

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731126/location-of-the-android-sdk-has-not-been-set-up-in-the-preferences-in-64-bit-win#comment24093386_16731284

Comment: thanks M8 I was struggling with this for hours

Comment: @thewhistler, please create an answer with the part after "EDIT: Solved!" and accept it. This solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, one on Windows 7 64bit machine the JAVA_HOME trick did work: i.e. set JAVA_HOME = your jdk bin directory. Also add the jdk bin directory to your path.

On my other Windows 7 64bit machine I had more problems. 
I tried downloading a different find_java.bat - it didn't help.
I tried setting ANDROID_SWT=lib\x86_64 - that helped a bit.

Eventually I stuck with the JAVA_HOME and path changes, then skipped installing the android sdk, installed the ADT Plugin into eclipse. From there, after you reboot, you should see SDK Manager available in the eclipse Help menu. I ran it from there and it was all smooth sailing.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the cmd screen showing up briefly then disappearing, **added pointer for Java to the path** as it was addressed earlier in one of these posts, it *did not solve the problem*. Then I **installed Java SDK**, it *did not solve* the problem. Then I added the **Java_HOME variable** but *it did not solve the problem*.

I started navigating via the directory files where the sdk files are installed on the `c: drive`, it is called "sdk".

- I found "andoroid" file under "tools" with the file type Windows Batch File.
- Clicked on it and it opened the sdk manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning down the strength of the [User Access Control](http://www.onecomputerguy.com/windows7/windows7_uac.htm) settings.

Comment: @ Graham : How it will be useful?? please check my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731126/location-of-the-android-sdk-has-not-been-set-up-in-the-preferences-in-64-bit-win#comment24093386_16731284

Answer (score 0):

I have 64 bit Windows 7 and so far no problems with SDK manager.

I have both 32 and 64 bit JDK's installed (JDK-6, not 7), but Java home points only to 64 bit Java. Check also your registry value for Java home:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.6.0_20\JavaHome
```

it should point to your 64 bit JDK. It's better to do it using Java widget from your Control Panel -> Programs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing two variable settings:

- set java_exe=**%JAVA_HOME%** - use JAVA_HOME if you have set system global varibale!
- for /f %%a in ('%java_exe% -jar **%work_dir%**\lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
  Missed local variable which is bold.

I made this changes and it is work for me
System: Windows7 x64
IDE: Eclipse JUNO x64

Answer (score 0):

I updated my paths the same as this and my SDK started to work.

JAVA_HOME points to my jdk directory

ANDROID_SDK_HOME points to my android sdk directory

ANDROID_SWT points to %ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\tools\lib\x86_64 (yes swt.jar is here)

PATH points to C:\Windows\System32 (yes xcopy.exe is here) and %JAVA_HOME%\bin (yes java.exe is here) and also %ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\platform-tools

[Click Here for more info](http://iqwen.net/question/162735)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having JDK in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\" and due to that whenever I use to start SDK both form SDKmanager.exe and through Eclipse it was not coming up.

So I copied JDK in C:/ and updated the path and it started working. (the issue was space in JAVA_HOME path)

Answer (score 0):

In order to better debug the problem, run the sdk/tools/android.bat application from the command line.  This will likely spit out the error message that is lost if the cmd window closes automatically, such as when you just double click the executable.

Also for completeness of the answers to this question, try running the sdk manager as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Downloaded all the appropriate files and unzipped into `C:\Development` folder. Opened Eclipse, Select Windows drop down box. Start SKD Manager from this location. Worked for me!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on stackoverflow and I hope it'll help you to figure out your problem.

A. Just go to command prompt and simply type android if you have installed android studio before, it'll work.

B. If you only need to download sdk then open this [link](https://chocolatey.org/install) follow such steps. After following such steps, go to windows powershell and type choco install android-sdk -y, it will only install the sdk manager. After completing everything go to command prompt and run android as an command. it will figure out your problem.

Comment: Please answer new and unanswered questions instead. Also your answer won't help as you literally just enumerated the steps to run the SDK Manager. I am sure the person who posted this would have tried this already. Also the question already says the problem is solved.