# Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences in 64 bit Windows

Tags: android, adt

"Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences in 64 bit Windows" - I know this problem has been addressed before several times, but rather than comment on an old question I decided to make a new one because still it's not solved.

Recently I changed my system from 32 to 64 and currently I cant Run my ADT. When am using 32 its works fine. I installed 64 bit ADT (Build: v21.1.0-569685) and updated everything. Now My ADT contains 6.41 GB.

Now when am trying to run Eclipse I got a popup like
[image]

When I am searching this I got a solution like **Window -> Preference -> Android -> SDK Location Set the path of the Android SDK in your computer there.**

But when I am trying for this OK button is not enabled. 
[image]

When I am trying to Access AVD again a popup came
[image]

When I am trying to create a new Project, another Popup is shown like

[image]

When I am trying to update - Mo Updates Found message is showing

[image]
Can anybody offer some advice on this problem?

Comment: `again a popup came` ... *made my day*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How to Update your ADT to Latest Version?

In Eclipse go to **Help**

Install New Software ---> **Add**

inside Add Repository write the Name: **ADT** (as you want)

and Location: **https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/**

after loading some time you will get **Developer Tools and NDK Plugins**

check both if you want to use NDK in the future or check Developer Tool only

click **Next**

**Finish**

Now My Problem Solved :-)

Comment: I did all of this and I'm still having the same problem, any tips?

Comment: Me too I still have the problem

Comment: Be sure you tick the radio button that says update, so it will uninstall any old versions you have.

Comment: i face error : Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518

Answer (score 6):

The issue may arise if you are running IntelliJ Idea or any other IDE that uses / shares the same Android SDK. After running IntelliJ Idea, and thereafter running Eclipse, the Eclipse IDE fails to get the path of the SDK. In Eclipse go to `Window > Preferences > Android` and change the back slashes to forward slashes. For e.g, `D:\eclipse\android-sdk` to `D:/eclipse/android-sdk` and press Apply.

Comment: +1 This fixed my issue and I did not have to update any ADT components.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue
     Solution:  go to the below URl https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip Extract the folder and now go to the preferences and select the SDK folder from the Extracted Folder, and apply it . the problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences, find "Android" on the sidebar and then there will be a box for SDK location, point it to the SDK. Read over http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html if you're still stuck.

OR

Go To Eclipse >> Windows >> Preferences and click on the left tab Android and you will see the below image with some text above as

“This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 14.0.0 or above.  Current version is 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486.  Please update ADT to the latest version.”

And Update..

Go to Eclipse >> Help >> Check for Updates.

Please don’t forget to close Eclipse after the Updates complete.

Comment: I did all the procedures which you mentioned in your answer. But still the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

How to update your ADT to the latest version:

1. In Eclipse go to Help ---> Install New Software ---> Add ---> Add Repository
2. Write the Name: ADT (as you want) and Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. After loading some time, you will get Developer Tools and NDK Plugins
4. Check both if you want to use NDK in the future, or check Developer Tool only
5. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>
6. <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Comment: After this I got the following error: `Only one of the following can be installed at once` Any idea?

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.4.1468518

Answer (score 0):

It means the "Android SDK" folder is empty, that's why it does not want to add it to Eclipse. Here are the contents of the Android SDK folder:

Windows: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip

Mac: https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

Download and extract the contents to a new folder and name it **android-sdk** and link that directory to Eclipse and you are all set!

[image]