# "Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences" error

Tags: android, eclipse, ssl, sdk

I do realise something like this has already been asked and I've followed through various solutions but can't find a fix.

I have already installed the software by including the link:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

and then restarted Eclipse, but then it's giving me the error mentioned in the title. I tried then using this:

http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

but it's telling me it's already installed and the same happens again when I just try to download the zipped package and install it that way.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731126/location-of-the-android-sdk-has-not-been-set-up-in-the-preferences-in-64-bit-win) yet?

Comment: Yes I have and I am still getting problems.

Answer (score 1):

If Towhidul's answer didn't work, I think the problem is with choosing the correct SDK path.

1. All Programs > Android SDK Tools > SDK Manager
   ( if you are using the latest Android Studio, open Android studio >
   SDK Manager > )
2. Now you will see the correct SDK path at the top left corner of the Android SDK Manager window ( eg:- "SDK Path: C:\Users\Malith\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)

Comment: Thanks for giving SDK path example :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue... Go to
Eclipse > window > Android SDK manager > Click on Install packages.
Wait for a while.
I hope this will work. Because it did work for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue
go to the below URl
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip
Extract the folder
and now go to the preferences 
and select the SDK folder from the Extracted Folder, and apply it . the problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue need to do following step:

1. Open eclips.
2. Go to window >> Preferences.
3. Then select Android.
4. In SDK Lication: need to brows correct SDK path.

This works for me.