# SDK Manager crash on installation

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to install the `android SDK` in my windows 64 bit OS but I'm not able to do it. Its getting crash every time i try to install I'm not able to find the exact problem i have searched every where i did't get any proper solution.

I have seen some of the solution here but its not working for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663996/sdk-manager-wont-start-windows-7-64-bit) . In this link they given the  solution like i have to add the

> Variable name:android  Variable value:C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\

Even after adding that variables in the system variable its still not working please give a proper solution to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `Java` installed on your machine?

Comment: @cosmincalistru ya i have already installed java in my machine

Comment: well, than maybe it's located somewhere else. When you enter `C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_60` in your `Windows Explorer` does it find the folder?

Comment: @cosmincalistru this is my C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin file directory i have already tried with this one also its not working